# smallest possible size of a sample using the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability-distributions

It appears that in this question I could be missing something or is it?

X bar, the mean of a sample of n independent observation of X, is Normally distributed such that P(z > 0.25)< 0.1.

Find the smallest possible value of n.

Could there be a case of missing value ; am getting n = 25 rather than 44

Comment: There is not enough information here. You need to know the distribution of $X$ itself.

Comment: What is CLT?  And why wouldn't you write out that acronym to increase the number of possible helpers?

Comment: what is $z$ in your writing ?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Refers to central limit theorem.@AhmadBazzi seems to refer to the standardized random variable

Comment: Oh sorry for CLT- central limit theorem, Z - standardized random variable and no more info was given. Thanks.

Comment: @WaitaraMburu that $Z$ should be X bar, the value is $n=25$ in the case you are working with only 1 tail and $n=44$ if you are working with both tails. (I think the expression is $P(|\bar{X}|>0.25)<0.1$)

Comment: Thank you Daniel, got it!